# Non-floating / Fixed header views in plain tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The header views in my plain style table view currently scrolls with the content. Is there a way to stop the header views from scrolling and stay in place at the top of the table?

Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible at this time. I worked around this by creating a table view that only partially fills a screen.